# How can I use Android's Navigation Architecture Component with Bazel?

Tags: android, bazel

I'm trying to update an old Android app to use the modern Single Activity model using the Navigation Architecture Component. How can I do this with Bazel?

My app already uses Bazel to build, but looks like the Navigation framework requires a gradle plugin:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

It's not obvious to me how to make this work with Bazel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no requirement to use the Safe Args Gradle Plugin to use Navigation (the runtime itself has no dependency on Gradle, etc). As per the [Pass Data documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#bundle), you can use Bundles to pass arguments as an alternative.

The `res/navigation` folder support is part of `aapt2`. As per [this Bazel issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6907), `aapt2` is not yet the default for Bazel. As per the [linked commit](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/dc7928c5dff832dbd35dc7899986d54d894b6c16):

> To build with aapt2 today, pass the flag `--incompatible_use_aapt2_by_default=true` or `--android_aapt=aapt2`, or set the `aapt_version`  to `aapt2` on your `android_binary` or `android_local_test` target.

Comment: I tried creating a res/navigation/navigation.xml file and the build fails with: invalid resource directory name: /tmp/resource_validator_tmp16830506611643002477/tmp-expanded/res navigation. I added a dependency on the navigation-runtime and navigation-fragment 2.0.0 libraries to the Bazel build.

Comment: I added a note to my answer about `res/navigation` which is a separate issue from the Gradle Plugin thing and is related to Bazel using `aapt` instead of `aapt2` (which was the default for Gradle from November 2017 onward).

Comment: Thank you, Ian. The flag to use aapt2 fixed the res/navigation issue. No other build issues so far.